# nodejs change inheritance of a class that inherit from another class

Tags: node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have class A in nodeJS(ES6) that inherit from class B. how can i create class C that extends {class A that extends class D rather than B} ?

```
class A extends B {}
class C extends <class A extends class D>
```

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to go against the entire concept of OOP. This suggests that either you've structured your classes wrong or that you probably shouldn't be using inheritance here.

Comment: I mean, it's not impossible, but really ugly. But the fact that you want this is an indication that your code is not architectured correctly. Maybe `A` shouldn't extend `B` or `D` but take an instance of those as a dependency. *edit:* What VLAZ said.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I know that it should have another architecture but i can't change the project architecture at this time. the main problem is that i don't want to change class C when I change class A. another way is to make class C from class D but manually change C when A developed.